# Как выровнять 3 div'а относительно внешнего?

Tags: css, html

Как выровнять по центру 3 div'а: `#stack-wrapper`, `#lshelf-wrapper` и `#rshelf-wrapper` относительно div'а `#canvases` ?

```css
#canvases {
  display: table;
  width: 500px;
  height: 310px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
#lshelf-wrapper,
#rshelf-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  float: left;
}
#stack-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  margin: 0 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvases">
  <div id="lshelf-wrapper">
    <canvas id="lshelf" width="150" height="40"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div id="stack-wrapper">
    <canvas id="stack" width="50" height="300"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div id="rshelf-wrapper">
    <canvas id="rshelf" width="150" height="40"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно заюзать `display: flex;` для `#canvases` и применить свойство `justify-content: space-around;`:

```css
#canvases {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 500px;
  height: 310px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
#lshelf-wrapper,
#rshelf-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  float: left;
}
#stack-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  margin: 0 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvases">
  <div id="lshelf-wrapper">
    <canvas id="lshelf" width="150" height="40"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div id="stack-wrapper">
    <canvas id="stack" width="50" height="300"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div id="rshelf-wrapper">
    <canvas id="rshelf" width="150" height="40"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: В сафари у меня ничего не изменилось, а в хроме они выровнялись по вертикали, но мне нужно выравнивание по горизонтали.

Comment: @0x1337, Ну указал бы что ли по какой оси выровнять.
Сейчас перепишу тогда.

Comment: @0x1337, То, что нужно?

Comment: Будет то, что нужно, если изменить `space-around` на `center`. Спасибо большое!

Comment: @0x1337, он немного по другому сделает, но как как угодно. Пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

норм?

```css
#canvases {
  display: table;
  width: 500px;
  height: 310px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
#lshelf-wrapper,
#rshelf-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  float: left;
}
#rshelf-wrapper{
  float:right
}

#stack-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px dashed #808080;
  margin: 0 10px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 14%;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvases">
    <div id="rshelf-wrapper">
    <canvas id="rshelf" width="150" height="40"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div id="lshelf-wrapper">
    <canvas id="lshelf" width="150" height="40"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div id="stack-wrapper">
    <canvas id="stack" width="50" height="300"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Чем абсолютное позиционирование не устраивает, ну или таблица, если совсем никак

или вы имели ввиду нечно такое?

```css
#canvases {
  width: 500px;
  height: 310px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
#lshelf-wrapper,
#rshelf-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  float: left;
}
#stack-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  margin: 0 10px;
  float: left;
}
.fw {
  width: 380px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvases">
  <div class="fw">
    <div id="lshelf-wrapper">
      <canvas id="lshelf" width="150" height="40"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div id="stack-wrapper">
      <canvas id="stack" width="50" height="300"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div id="rshelf-wrapper">
      <canvas id="rshelf" width="150" height="40"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это не совсем то, что нужно. Получается большое отступ между центральным блоком и боковыми. Есть ли способ сделать так, чтобы этот отступ изменялся margin'ом? Т.е. при margin: 0 они соприкасаются, как в моем первом сообщении.

Comment: @0x1337, второй вариант в ответе?

Comment: Да, второй вариант похож на истину, но он сильно привязан к размерам, например при изменении ширины крайних блоков все "сползает".  Вот, посмотрите пример https://jsfiddle.net/y3tw0wLs/1/ , при изменении ширины инпутов они как-бы расширяются в стороны. Мне нужно получить, что то похожее только с этими блоками.